Nuscence dataset LiDAR Radar visualisation
I am trying to visualize LIDAR_TOP and all the 5 RADAR points using cloudcompare or open3d tools. After visualization I observed the radar and lidar points are not aligned. Blue points are from lidar and red points from radar.


No code is used. It's Nuscence data. Just superimposed lidar over radar data in cloudcompare

"No code is used" -- would that mean that the question is not about programming or software development, and thus off-topic?

It's about calibration or need to use any rotation matrix. Which I couldn't find
